# Loading parquet file in bigquery using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('credentials.json')
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials)            
    table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
         autodetect=True,
         source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET,
    )
    with open(data.parquet, 'rb') as source_file:
        load_job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
    load_job.result()
```

Above is what I am doing to upload data on bigquery. My confusion:

1. Where is this data getting stored? as gcp bucket is empty but I am able to query uploaded file in bigquery!
2. Any way to ensure duplicate keys are overwriten like what happen in mysql?
3. Any way to generate password like user_id, password, port etc and use that instead of a json of credentials?

Comment: Please, review BigQuery features, limits and capabilities.

Comment: couldn't find it in that!

Comment: Maybe because it does not exist! No primary/foreign key management (you can find the definition, but the constraint is not enforce), and you can only use IAM permission to access BigQuery (and using a service account key file is a bad partice, read the Note: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#wlif-key). And the data loaded in BigQuery are stored in BigQuery. You can also use federated query to request data in GCS. So, read the doc first!